# clone 1 row of divs with another on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 rows.   Each row has 3 individual DIVs that can be selected (Clicked) by the user.  When the the user clicks on any of the DIVs on the first row, there is styling in CSS to change the colour of the individual DIV (column if you like) I would like the corresponding DIV (column) in the 2nd row of DIVs to show as selected too.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="price">£20,944</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="price2">£20,944</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="price3">£20,944</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard time active h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="time">13:00</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard time h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="time2">15:00</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
      <div class="card pricecard time h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span class="time3">18:00</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery-

```
let $divs = $('.pricecard.aircraft').click(function() {
    $divs.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/f9Lc0yjk/

Comment: So add a class to the parent

Comment: @epascarello not sure what you mean?

Comment: @epascarello, thanks but this doesnt help me... I created a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/f9Lc0yjk/

Comment: So if I click the second div in the first group, you also want to highlight the second div in the second group, is that right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats right, and if you select second div on second row it should highlight second div on first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a solution would be to use jQuery [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get a column number.

Since the elements you target are in some `div.col-*`, you have to check for the index of the parent.

Then, having a column number, you can target the relevant elements on the other rows.

```js
$('.pricecard').click(function() {
  
  // Get the parent's index of the clicked one
  let columnNum = $(this).parent().index()

  // For each...
  $('.pricecard').each(function() {
  
    // Add the class if the parent's index is the same as the clicked one
    $(this).toggleClass('active', ($(this).parent().index() === columnNum));
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="price">£20,944</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="price2">£20,944</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="price3">£20,944</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard time active h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="time">13:00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard time h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="time2">15:00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
    <div class="card pricecard time h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="time3">18:00</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Louys.. that pretty much does what I need it to do.. my only question is how can I adapt this so that users can click on the 2nd row of DIVs to also update the 1st row?

Comment: Yes! in fact, is quite simplifies the thing. ;) I edited.

Comment: Ho! And I noticed that line `$(this).clone().append(".pricecard.thirdparty");` which was useless... I don't know what was the intend. So I removed it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Louys .. that does exactly what I want  :)